# Android reading html file from external storage

Tags: android, android-webview

I am trying to show the html files in /storage/sdcard0/...

```
WebView engine = (WebView) (findViewById(R.id.webView1));
engine.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
engine.loadUrl(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "testing.html");
```

but the webpage failed to display.... Can anybody help? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SOLVED!!!
should add "file:///" in the front =]=]

```
engine.loadUrl("file:///" + 
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + 
"testing.html");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
engine.loadUrl("file:///"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "testing.html");
```